# NHibernate ICriteria subqueries with ISet<T> properties: Is this correct?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, criteria, subquery

Given a class A related to another class B in a one-to-many relationship, how can you create an NHibernate query (using the Criteria API--no HQL) to find all objects A who "have none" of the related objects B?  Specifics follow, but I wanted to get the question out there first.

I have two model classes, **Sample** and **SampleDiagnosis**.  Sample has a *Diagnoses* property which is an ISet<SampleDiagnosis>.  SampleDiagnosis has an *Owner* property which links back to the sample.  It is a simple one-to-many relationship.

The relevant section of my Sample NHibernate mapping file looks like this:

```
<set name="Diagnoses" table="sample_diagnoses" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
  <key column="sample_id" />
  <one-to-many class="SampleDiagnosis" />
</set>
```

The relevant piece of the SampleDiagnosis mapping file looks like this:

```
<many-to-one name="Owner" class="Sample" column="sample_id" />
```

I am trying to create an NHibernate ICriteria query that will match Samples that do not have any items in their *Diagnoses* list.  Here is the code I am using to build my test query:

```
var dc = DetachedCriteria.For<Sample>();

var subcriteria = dc.CreateCriteria("Diagnoses").SetProjection(Projections.RowCount());

dc.Add(Subqueries.Eq(0, subcriteria));
```

In my mind, the SQL generated for this would look something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM samples WHERE (select count(*) from sample_diagnoses where sample_diagnoses.sample_id = samples.sample_id) = 0
```

However, when actually doing a GetExecutableCriteria() and List()ing the results, my code crashes. Hard. No exceptions are thrown, but whatever happened to be running the code (be it NUnit or w3p.exe) dies a horrible death. I've tried it on multiple machines, all with the same result.  I have a feeling I am missing something crucial about how subqueries work with sets in NHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, what I was looking for was **Expression.IsEmpty("Diagnoses")**.

Answer (score 1):

This would be **SO** much easier via HQL - just sayin' :)

Did you try using `size`? Something like:

```
var dc = DetachedCriteria.For<Sample>();
dc.Add(Expression.sizeEq("Diagnoses", 0) );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SizeEq is part of Hibernate, but not NHibernate!).  However, you did inspire me to go back and more closely examine the API, and Expression.IsEmpty("Diagnoses") DOES work.

Comment: Indeed, I picked up that trick working with Hibernate :-)
I knew for a fact that `size` function works in NHibernate HQL, but wasn't sure about criteria. Glad you've figured it out.